# EditText with imeOptions

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
        android:imeOptions="actionGo"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"/>
```

I need the text written in EditText not to go beyond the bounds. It will moving on the lines. `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` will not work, because there is also `android:imeOptions="actionGo"`, and if I use MultiLine, then Enter doesn't changing to the GO button. 
P.S.
Sorry for my bad language ;)

Comment: I'll try it soon

Comment: Thank you a lot ;)